# Finding surface area cut from a sphere

Tags: surface-integrals

I wish to find the surface area cut from the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ and the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$

Here is what i tried:
by uniting the 2 equations we get: $z=1$

The shape looks like a dome, when:

$0\lt z\lt 1$
$0\lt r\lt \sqrt 2$
$0\lt \theta \lt 2\pi$

I'm not sure how to continue from here. any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know about surface integrals, from multivariable calculus? If so, what happened when you tried to set up the surface integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cylinder cuts out two spherical caps from the sphere. The radius of the sphere is $\sqrt 2$, and the two planes defining these caps have equations $z=\pm1$. It follows that the height of these caps is $\sqrt{2}-1$. By a standard theorem (maybe found out by Archimedes) the area of each cap is equal to the area of a cylinder enveloping the sphere around the equator, enclosed between the planes $z=1$ and $z=\sqrt{2}$. It follows that the area per cap is $2\pi\,\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)=2\pi(2-\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: I know understand! if i wanted to  solve as a surface integral it should be: $\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2}d\theta\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}dz$. adding up all the "slices" between $1\lt z \lt \sqrt 2$. Am i right?

Comment: The resulting integral would be $$2\pi\bigl(\sqrt{2}\bigr)^2\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin\theta\>d\theta\ ,$$ whereby $\theta=0$ at the north pole.

Comment: why is $0\lt \theta \lt \frac{\pi}{4}$?